# Growth rate of variable y as a function of growth in variable x

Tags: derivatives, related-rates

Consider a functional form:

$y_t$ = a$x_t$ + b     ...(1)

Where, $x_t$ grows at rate g ie. $(x_{t+1} - x_t)/x_t$ = g

Find the growth rate of y?

Solution: Differentiating (1) wrt to time t

$\dot{y_t}$ = a$\dot{x_t}$

Dividing both sides by $y_t$

$\frac{\dot{y_t}}{y_t}$ = $\frac{\dot{ax_t}}{ax_t +b}$

My problem is how to bring in g into the above equation so that growth of y can be expressed in terms of growth of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $\,\,\displaystyle \frac{x_{t+1}-x_t}{x_t}=g$, then $x_{t+1}=(1+g)x_t$, and so $y_{t+1}=a(1+g)x_t+b$.

Then, $\displaystyle \frac{y_{t+1}-y_t}{y_t}=\frac{agx_t}{ax_t+b}$. Due to  $b$, the growth rate isn't expressible solely as a function of $g$.